# Analyze theta relation between sum of sqrt(i) and n*sq-root(n)

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

i want try to prove that:

> sum of i^1/2 with i = 1 to n

and

> n^3/2

are equal as asymptotic.
How can I prove this relation?

Comment: Where is the partial work that you have done so far to try to figure this out on your own?

Comment: You mean `(2/3)n^(3/2)`. For a proof (non-trivial by the way) refer to the mathematics stack exchange site.

Comment: If this is a "homework question", please show what work or research you've done up to this point. We can provide you more useful answers (and your question will be more useful to other readers) when you show your full thinking about the topic.

Comment: i want solve this:T(n)=T(n-1)+n^1/2 and i found this series sum of i^1/2 with i = 1 to n is n^3/2. but i want a proof for that